# Summation Algebra: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

What rule do we use to get the numerical value of $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$ 
My notes give the answer straight away, without explaining what the steps are.

// Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hint: it's geometric progression.

Comment: This is a geometric serie (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Just use the formula of sum of infinite GP S=a/1-r

Comment: Hint 2: Make a index shift. $k=n-1$

Comment: @Nicolas: tiny nitpick, the English singular of "series" is "series". "This is a geometric series."

Comment: @PatrickStevens Really? I did not know that! Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = \frac12 + \frac14+\frac18 +\cdots$$
This is a geometric series with $a = \frac12$ and $r = \frac12$. So our sum is $$\frac{a}{1-r} = \frac{\frac12}{1-\frac12} = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

You may just check that, in general,
$$
(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^N)=1-x^{N+1} \tag1
$$ giving easily
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty}(x+x^2+\cdots+x^N)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1. \tag2
$$ Then put $x:=\dfrac12$ in $(2)$ to get your sum:

> $$
> \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=1.
> $$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-2}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+...\right)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

This is just an infinite geometric progression with initial term $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and common ratio $r=\frac{1}{2}$ so that the sum of the terms converges as $|r|<1$ so that the sum is given by $\frac{a}{(1-r)}=1$.